# Projecting query from DTO which derived from Entity

Tags: entity-framework, automapper, dto

Considering blogging data model:

```
Blog: 
Id
Name
Posts

Posts: 
Id 
BlogId
Date
Blog

BlogDto: Blog
LastPostDate

PostDto: Post
BlogName
```

The DTOs derived from the entities since all the properties are shared, and the DTO just have some extra ones. Also, based on needs, some different mapping in Automapper are defined:

```
Post -> PostDto
PostDto -> Post
Post -> Post
PostDto -> PostDto

Blog -> Blog Dto
Blog Dto -> Blog 
Blog -> Blog 
Blog Dto -> Blog Dto
```

Then I want to project a query from Post to PostDto (with AutoMapper.EF6) like this:

```
dbContext.Set<Post>
    .Include("Blog")
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ProjectToListAsync<PostDto>();
```

But I encounter this error:

```
"The entity or complex type 'Blog' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query".
```

The tip is if I remove the Post -> Post mapping, the error does not appear. I guess because AutoMapper try to map the nested PostDto.Blog navigation property in projection.

Is my approach wrong (DTO inherits from Entity)? If so, I guess the best practice is to define the DTO with repeating all the members inside the Entity, which is bothering!
If not, how can I manage nested mapping here?

Comment: Have you configured the autoMapper to convert the entities to dto?

Comment: @FelipeOriani Yes. The second part shows all defined mappings (Post -> PostDto, PostDto -> Post, and etc.).

Comment: Add the code you have used to configure the autoMapper. If possible, add the code of `Post` and `PostDto` classes.

Comment: @FelipeOriani Since I couldn't share my code here, I described the problem with blogging model which has the same structure. But if you think it should not happen in this simple model, I can implement this sample and share the code. My question was about the approach and I didn't think it is related to implementation details. Also the mapping is very simple like CreateMap<Post, PostDto>();

Comment: Looks like your `PostDto` contains a `Blog` property. The `Blog -> Blog` mapping creates a new `Blog` entity. You should configure AM to use the original entity object. FYI, `Include` is redundant when projecting.

Comment: @GertArnold That's one of my questions. How to configure the AM to avoid that? Also if we do it, is it OK that PostDto has Blog navigation and not BlogDto navigation. Since I think also navigations inside the Dto should be a Dto.